# CSS for getting text in below Alignment

Tags: css

Need your input for css for displaying text in following format, I need to break a line into two and then move the below line to middle:

My Current Text :

```
PLEASE NOTE :  System  Down for Maintainance from 12th Friday 2013 until 13th Saturday 2013
```

Required :

```
PLEASE NOTE :  System  Down for Maintainance from 12th Friday 2013 
until 13th Saturday 2013
```

Comment: Right-click one of the coloured words and hit "Inspect Element" - your browser's Developer Tools will tell you - both the html structure and the requisite css

Comment: What format do you mean? Markdown code highlight or putting message right to title?

Comment: My Text is in one line , I need to display it in the above format , I need to move botton line ... How Can i achieve that

Comment: Your question is very vague. Do you have access to edit the DOM, is there a reason you need to do this specifically with CSS instead of just creating two *paragraph* elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CSS classes. Here's a simple implementation using 3 classes for each color.

```
font.color1 {color:Red;}
font.color2 {color:blue;}
font.color3 {color:gray;}
```

You can then use these classes in the statement like so

```
PLEASE NOTE :  
<font class = "color1">System  Down </font> 
<font class = "color2">for </font> 
<font class = "color1">Maintenance </font> 
<font class = "color2">from </font>
<font class = "color3">12th </font>
<font class = "color1">Friday </font>
<font class = "color3">2013 </font>
<font class = "color2">until </font>
<font class = "color3">13th </font>
<font class = "color1">Saturday </font>
<font class = "color3">2013 </font>
```

Please take care to give the spaces at the end of each word.

Alternatively you can just use php or javascript to generate the classes by giving an Id to each font tag (or whichever tag you prefer).

Stack overfolow uses span> to a similar effect. I've used the font> tag instead

EDIT:
font> is decrepated. Heres the same thing using span:

```
span.color1 {color:#xxx;}
span.color2 {color:#xxx;}
span.color3 {color:#xxx;}
```

You can then use these classes in the statement like so

```
PLEASE NOTE :   
<span class = "color1">System  Down </span> 
<span class = "color2">for </span> 
<span class = "color1">Maintenance </span> 
<span class = "color2">from </span>
<span class = "color3">12th </span>
<span class = "color1">Friday </span>
<span class = "color3">2013 </span>
<span class = "color2">until </span>
<span class = "color3">13th </span>
<span class = "color1">Saturday </span>
<span class = "color3">2013 </span>
```

Now to break the line into two you have to use a div> tag and two span> tags together
i.e place a div> as a wrapper. Then two span> tags as two seperate statements.

I don't understand how you want to break the line. Could you explain more clearly, I can follow with the code for the div> and span> then..

Comment: No, the font tag is deprecated and has been for a long time. Do not use the font tag.

Comment: Yeah disule is correct. Its just better to use span instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you can use a br tag? or perhaps:

```
<span class="title">PLEASE NOTE :</span>
<span class="note">System  Down for Maintainance from 12th Friday    
2013 until 13th Saturday 2013</span>
```

with CSS:

```
.title:after {
   content: "\A";
   white-space: pre;
}
```

Created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jennift/9SQ34/